# add a primary key to an existing union query in access 2010

Tags: sql, excel, ms-access

I have linked two tables from excel two different excel files that input data into my union query in  ms access 2010, my question is can I add a primary key to the already existing union query?

Both tables from excel have very similar information and in access their field names are identical. I need the first column called MRN to become the primary key, so I won't have duplicate MRN's from the same station(FYI the two excel files with the linked tables are stations in which products are scanned and their data is then transmitted into access through the linked tables) this is what I have in sql already:

```
    SELECT [OvenImportTable].[F1] As MRN,[OvenImportTable].[F2] As Description,[OvenImportTable].[F3] As [TWI Part #], 
    [OvenImportTable].[F4] As [PO #], [OvenImportTable].[F5] As REC,[OvenImportTable].[F6] As EXP, [OvenImportTable].[F7] As Station
    FROM [OvenImportTable]
    UNION SELECT 
    [DiePunchImportTable].[F1], [DiePunchImportTable].[F2], [DiePunchImportTable].[F3],
    [DiePunchImportTable].[F4],[DiePunchImportTable].[F5],
    [DiePunchImportTable].[F6], [DiePunchImportTable].[F7]
    FROM [DiePunchImportTable,
    alter table MRN add primary key;
```

This is what one record in the first table looks like:

```
    MRN   Description TWI Part # PO# REC      EXP     Station                 
    1234-1 312HTG   400-134004 123 08/15/14 08/15/15 Oven
```

this is what one record in the second table looks like:

```
MRN   Description TWI Part # PO# REC       EXP       Station
1234-1 312HTG    400-134004  123 08/15/14  08/15/15  Punch
```

The result I would like to see is making the MRN a unique number, so it is not duplicated by human error. I need to add a primary key to both tables so the MRN isn't accidentally duplicated in those tables. I am wondering if it is possible to add this operation to SQL? Is it even possible in a union query?

Any help or suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: If you have duplicated data, which should be returned -- the first table or the second?  Perhaps sample data and expected results would help...

Comment: @sgeddes hope this is easier to understand, the reason I want to use sql to add the primary keys is because from what I understand you can't add primary keys to linked tables.